# C# class with multiple naming

Tags: c#, class, runtime-error

I referenced an external assembly (dll) in my project and that assembly has several versions.

Problem is that assembly changed some class names and I got runtime errors when I use them. For example in some version class name is `BipedDriver` and for other is `BipedMaster`.

Question: is it possible to use a class with different name and decide when to use it? For example if reference assembly version is 1000, the class name is `BipedDriver` otherwise is `BipedMaster`?

Comment: Is the application simultaneously referencing multiple versions of the dependency?  Why, and how would it know which one to use?

Comment: You code need to get the version of the dll and based on version execute different code.  That is what IF statement are used for.

Comment: Are you not able to fix the `dll`. That looks to be the root of the problem

Comment: My dll will load in 3dsMax and refrenced assemblies are different version od wrappers for the 3dsMax SDK called Autodesk.max.dll. I know we should use specific SDK version for desired build, But If we solve this error, I'm able to run single dll for more than 10 versions of the 3dsMax. And I'm not able to edit Autodesk.max.dll.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap and abstract the 3rd party dependencies with your own domain-specific naming.

For example, create your own interface which exposes the operations that you need the dependencies to perform:

```
public interface IBiped
{
    // define your own method names here
}
```

And create two implementations (or as many as you like, really):

```
public class MyBipedMaster : IBiped
{
    // implement your interface using "BipedMaster"
}

public class MyBipedDriver : IBiped
{
    // implement your interface using "BipedDriver"
}
```

Then throughout your domain logic, everything can simply reference an instance of `IBiped`.  And wherever/however you have logic to determine which implementation to use is where you'd supply the implementation.  One simple example could be:

```
public class BipedFactory
{
    public static IBiped Create(bool someCondition)
    {
        if (someCondition)
            return new MyBipedDriver();
        else
            return new MyBipedMaster();
    }
}
```

And consuming code would never need to know which one is which:

```
var biped = BipedFactory.Create(someCondition);
```

How you abstract `someCondition` is up to you.  Perhaps instead of passing it to the factory it is something determined by the factory internally, for example.  Or you might not use an explicit factory at all, but instead build this logic into any dependency injection system you're using so that it knows which implementation to inject into any object that needs it.

Comment: My goal is not get different result based on different conditions. I just need single code that works for all versions of the referenced assembly, even with different names for single class (classes comes from referenced assembly, I don't have access to edit them).

Comment: @MehdiZangeneh: It’s not really clear what you’re trying to do then.  If your code is referencing two different versions of the same 3rd party library, how would your code know which one to use in any given instance?  If you don’t want to conditionally use one or the other, why do you need both?

Comment: I don't want ot use at the same time, let me explain it more, When 3dsMax loads my dll, it will reference it's Autodesk.max.dll, So 3dsMax 2024 will load autodesk.max.dll 2024, this version is differ from the version that I referenced in my VS.

Comment: This image will show my question better:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19w2-KOE7kzGY4sbaRkAQ82-N-hyulcbl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MehdiZangeneh: If you don’t want to simultaneously support both then I guess you’d pick which one you want to use and use that one. And if you need another version then you’d create a new version of your own code which supports it. So far it sounds like you want to be able to support both with a single build of your own code, but you’re saying that you don’t. So then it’s not really clear what the problem is. Either support one, or the other, or both (in which the code would need to determine which to conditionally use). You can’t support both while simultaneously not supporting both.

Comment: @MehdiZangeneh: What happens when you try to reference both versions of the dependency in your code?  Are you able to create and use an instance of either type successfully?

Comment: I think the image which I uploaded shows everything. One code for all. one dll will be loaded in each version of 3dsmax. and 3dsMax will load my dll with it's own Autodesk.max.dll, so I need to handle all naming.

Comment: If I add both references:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z0S09VIXOO4bP4TiuJGtkd36RdJPzA_Q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MehdiZangeneh: If you can’t reference both versions then I’m afraid you can’t support both versions.  You may want to contact the vendor on what they recommend, but it sounds like you may need to target specific versions in your software, and release different versions of your software that support different versions of the library.

Comment: Is Visual Studio able to automate changing reference and rename files just before the build? So we can build all one time?